# PHP Array 1 Value Extract - Gives Error

Tags: php, arrays

I know this question has been asked before.
but whenever I try to get the value of my array it does not work, only difference I can see is the name of a value is a number?

```
$returnValue = json_decode('{"content": [{"id": 1249029}]}');`
```

That gives me an array that looks like:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'content' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'id' => 1249029,
    )),
  ),
))
```

So getting my id should be as simple as:

```
var_dump($returnValue['content']->0->id);
```

This code gives me an error 500.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for the online eval. Seems it was my local php server that was behaving weirdly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access it like this:

```
$returnValue->content[0]->id;
```